# Power increase string for calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, calculator

i started with python a few days ago, i was looking if there was a more efficient way to display a power increase string on my calculator like : `2*2*2*2*2`, i cant delete based on character cause this would replace entire string i assume, so currently im converting it to a string, delete last value based of string length and rejoin it to a string again, could this be done in a more efficient way?

```
strw = str(str(sumX) + "*") * sumY
l = list(strw)
del (l[len(strw) - 1])
strw = "".join(l)
```

Comment: You may represent an exponent using _two_ `*`, e.g. `2**4` means `2^4`.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What are your inputs, and what's the desired output? What are `sumX` and `sumY`?

Answer (score 1):

use **list definition** and **.join()**:

You can multiply a list by an integer n to repeat the list n times,example:

```
n = 5
list_= [0] * n   # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

> The **join() method** takes all items in an iterable and joins them
>   into one string.
>
> A string must be specified as the separator.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> string.join(iterable)
> ```

```
sumX = 2
sumY = 5

print ('*'.join([str(sumX)] * sumY))
```

output:

```
2*2*2*2*2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join(...)` to do it in one neat line of code:

```py
'*'.join([str(sumX)] * sumY)
```

It yields this when `sumX=2` and `sumY=3`

`>>> '2*2*2'`

[Here is a link to the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). It works by "joining" the elements of the iterable with the '*'.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, 
Exactly what i was looking for (: